# Combined gesture never stops updating itself

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture

I would like to create a gesture which would require `LongTapGesture` before one of other two gestures (`DragGesture` and `MagnificationGesture`) is possible. It works fine for just dragging, but if you try to magnify it soon ends in a hangup state - looks like magnification never ends.

What would be the right way to do it?
Here's the code:

```
struct DraggableCircle: View {

    enum DragState {
        case inactive
        case pressing
        case draggingOrMagnifying(translation: CGSize, magnification: CGFloat)
        
        var translation: CGSize {
            switch self {
            case .inactive, .pressing:
                return .zero
            case .draggingOrMagnifying(let translation, _):
                return translation
            }
        }
        
        var magnification: CGFloat {
            switch self {
            case .inactive, .pressing:
                return 1
            case .draggingOrMagnifying(_, let magnification):
                return magnification
            }
        }
        
        var isActive: Bool {
            switch self {
            case .inactive:
                return false
            case .pressing, .draggingOrMagnifying:
                return true
            }
        }
        
        var isDragging: Bool {
            switch self {
            case .inactive, .pressing:
                return false
            case .draggingOrMagnifying:
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    
    @GestureState var dragState = DragState.inactive
    @State var viewState = CGSize.zero
    @State var magState = CGFloat(1)
    
    var body: some View {
            let minimumLongPressDuration = 0.5
            let longPressDrag = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: minimumLongPressDuration)
            .sequenced(before: DragGesture().exclusively(before: MagnificationGesture()))
                .updating($dragState) { value, state, transaction in
                    switch value {
                    // Long press begins.
                    case .first(true):
                        state = .pressing
                    // Long press confirmed, dragging may begin.
                    case .second(true, let exclusiveGesture):
                        switch exclusiveGesture {
                        case .first(let drag):
                            state = .draggingOrMagnifying(translation: drag.translation, magnification: 1)
                        case .second(let mag):
                            state = .draggingOrMagnifying(translation: .zero, magnification: mag)
                        case .none:
                            state = .draggingOrMagnifying(translation: .zero, magnification: 1)
                        }
                        
                        print(state)
                    // Dragging ended or the long press cancelled.
                    default:
                        state = .inactive
                    }
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    guard case .second(true, let gest?) = value else { return }
                    switch gest {
                case .first(let drag):
                    self.viewState.width += drag.translation.width
                    self.viewState.height += drag.translation.height
                case .second(let mag):
                    self.magState = magState * mag
                }
                    
                    
                }
        return Circle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .overlay(dragState.isDragging ? Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2) : nil)
            .frame(width: clipToBounds(100 * magState * dragState.magnification), height: clipToBounds(100 * magState * dragState.magnification), alignment: .center)
            .offset(
                x: viewState.width + dragState.translation.width,
                y: viewState.height + dragState.translation.height
            )
            .animation(nil)
            .shadow(radius: dragState.isActive ? 8 : 0)
            .animation(.linear(duration: minimumLongPressDuration))
            .gesture(longPressDrag)
    }
    
    func clipToBounds(_ m: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        if abs(m) > UIScreen.main.bounds.height {
            return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        } else {
            return abs(m)
        }
        
    }
}
```